# jquery $(function() ... styles, what's diff btw them

Tags: jquery

I have seen many jquery/js $(function()...

1.

```
$(function() {
      console.log('a'); 
})
```

2.

```
(function($) {

}(jQuery))
```

and so on

I just wanna choose one for me, which one should i choose?

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are entirely different.

The first one is dom ready event handler, the function passed to `$` will get executed on dom ready event. The problem with this is if you have used `jQuery.noConflict()`, `$` may not refer to `jQuery`

The second one is a anonymous function execution, where `$` inside the inner function will refer to jQuery, this is useful in cases where you have used `jQuery.noConflict()` to support other libraries like prototype/mootools. One drawback of this mechanism is still you will need to use dom ready handlers inside the inner function like

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        //your jQuery code
    })
}(jQuery))
```

**My Solution** will be as follows as it does both the above steps together

```
jQuery(function($) {
      console.log('a'); 
})
```